# Adding step to custom jQuery spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/V7c6y/1/). How can I add a step to the code to increment the value every time by adding 10 to the existing until getting to 100? and decrements the value until zero?

As I said I need to have a step on 10 number.

```
<div class="btn-group input-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default minus">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default opacity">% 0&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default plus">+</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    var i=1;
    $(".plus").on("click", function () {
        if(i<11) $(".opacity").html("% " +i++);
    });
    $(".minus").on("click", function () {
        if(i>0) $(".opacity").html("% " +i--);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var i=0;
    $(".plus").on("click", function () {
        if(i<10) $(".opacity").html("% " +((++i)*10));
    });
    $(".minus").on("click", function () {
        if(i>0) $(".opacity").html("% " +((--i)*10));
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7c6y/5/)

Comment: Thanks Michal but there is an issue here, after ending the number if you start to vote down there is an increment again + the number doesnot end at 0 it just vote down to 10!

Comment: Thanks Michal, I have another question about calling Multipile classes, like this http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/p2sc9/1/ do you think I should ask in new post? or you can tell me why is not functioning correctly!?

Comment: so in case of having 10 spinner I have to repeat the code 10 times?

Comment: Oh my god ! this is awesome, but very complicated! i need time to understand what exactly you did here! any thanks again!